# How can i make a template of my Visual Studio Solution files?

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation

i use n-tier programing on c# 
and i want to make a template to generate code easily (this is .cs, .csproj and .sln)

my question is, how can i make it? and 
if exist a software, which one you recomend???

it will be very useful your opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another templating engine is known as T4.  This is built in to Visual Studio.

Scott Hanselman wrote about this [in a blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A good templating and code generation engine is codesmith.

Code smith should be able to generate all the types of files you are looking for, SLN, CSProj and CS files.

You can also use the Visual Studio SDK to create project templates.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Factory:  http://solutionfactory.codeplex.com/releases/view/26598